# How to disable `useUnifiedTestPlatform` on Android Gradle Plugin 8.2+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-plugin-8.2

The Android Gradle Plugin AGP 8.2 deprecated the option `useUnifiedTestPlatform` however I still want to disable it. How can I disable `useUnifiedTestPlatform`?

The option setting This is the warning message: 'android.experimental.androidTest.useUnifiedTestPlatform=false' is deprecated. The current default is 'true'.